# Azure AD Graph API issue: Specified $skiptoken is invalid

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I get the following exception when trying to fetch AAD group transitive members using the Graph API:

> Specified $skiptoken is invalid.

Here is my code:

```
private IEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.User> GetGroupMembers(AccessLevel al) {
    var usersCollectionPage = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => Client.Groups[al.Id].TransitiveMembers.Request().GetAsync());
    foreach (var user in usersCollectionPage.CurrentPage.OfType<Microsoft.Graph.User>()) {
        yield return user;
    }
    while (usersCollectionPage.NextPageRequest != null) {
        var page = usersCollectionPage;
        usersCollectionPage = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => page.NextPageRequest.GetAsync());
        foreach (var user in usersCollectionPage.CurrentPage.OfType<Microsoft.Graph.User>()) {
            yield return user;
        }
    }
}
```

It fails on page.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().
I am using Microsoft.Graph version 4.11.
This used to work. I suspect it stopped working after upgrading the Graph SDK.
The issue happens in a production environment where there are enough group members to trigger paging.

Has anyone else seen the issue?

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.7: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/issues/345
I will test.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.7: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/issues/345